# Integration via substitution

Tags: integration

I require a hint for solving the differential equation;

$y\sqrt{\strut(1+(\frac{dy}{dx}})^2=c$

I assume it's done via an appropriate substitution

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** try $\frac {dy}{dx} = \sinh (u(x))$

Comment: How do i integrate this?